# Operating elementwise on an array

Tags: arrays, fortran, element, fortran90, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm trying to check if my arrays are returning nonsense by accessing out of bounds elements, in fortran. And I want to check these values are less than one, and if they are, change them to one.

This is the piece of my code causing issues:

`lastNeighLabel=(/clusterLabel(jj-1,kk,ll), clusterLabel(jj,kk-1,ll), clusterLabel(jj,kk,ll-1)/)`
LastNeighLabel contains the cluster label (between 1 and n, where n isthe total number of unique seperate clusters found) for the last neighbour in the x,y,z direction respectively.

When `jj` or `kk` or `ll` are 1, they try and access the 0th element in the array, and as `FORTRAN` counts from 1 in arrays, it tries to destroy the universe. I'm currently in a tangled mess of about 8 if/elseif statements trying to code for every eventuality. But I was hoping there was a way of operating on each element. So basically I'd like to say `where((/jj-1,kk-1,ll-1/).lt.1) do clusterLabel(jj-1,kk,ll)=0 etc` depending on which element is causing the problem.

But I can't think of a way to do that because where will only manipulate the variables passed to it, not a different array at the same index. Or am I wrong?

Will gladly edit if this doesn't make sense.

Comment: Do you want to have for example lastNeighLabel=(/0, clusterLabel(jj,kk-1,ll), clusterLabel(jj,kk,ll-1)/) if jj==0 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could use a function?

```
  real function f(A,i,j,k)  
   real :: A(:,:,:)
   integer :: i,j,k

   if (i==0.or.j==0.or.k==0) then
    f=0
   else
    f=A(i,j,k)
   endif

  end function f
```

and then use f(clusterLabel,jj-1,kk,ll) etc.

Comment: Ah I think I follow.

So if any of the elements of clusterLabel are 0 return 0?
How do I put that function into the programme? Will it return the array?

Comment: Yes I meant that.  And of course something similar for the upper bounds, you could pass the upper bound to the function or use UBOUND intrinsic.

Comment: The way I designed the code it only looks at the neighbours before (thus the -1) it should never look at the upper bound. If it does that, I'll follow your advice. Otherwise thanks. Going to try it now.

Comment: Should the else block be:
`f=A(i,j,k)` 
Else I can't see how it works.

Comment: I've made the else block as I stated above, now I get this error:

`fortcom: Error: percolation.f90, line 53: The number of subscripts is incorrect.   [CORRECTNEIGHLABEL]
print *, correctNeighLabel(clusterLabel(jj,kk,ll),jj,kk,ll-1)`

This is the case if I declare `correctNeighLabel` as having a dimension 3 or 4. And with or without passing the elements of clusterLabel. the function is definitely declared as having 4 inputs. I'm not sure whats wrong really.

Comment: Yes the else block was bad, correcting :) You should call it `correctNeighLabel(clusterLabel,jj,kk,ll-1)` with the array as argument not just some member, which may not exist.

Comment: Ok, I've done that and it didn't like it. I'm going back and figuring which of the many ways to include the function I need to use.

Comment: Should this sub-topic be forked?
This is my interface block
`interface`
`  function correctNeighLabel (A,i,j,k)`
`  integer :: correctNeighLabel`
`  integer, intent(in) :: i,j,k`
`  integer,dimension(:,:,:),intent(inout) :: A`
`end function`
`end interface`

This is my Function:
`function correctNeighLabel(A,i,j,k)`
`implicit none`
`integer :: A(:,:,:)`
`integer :: i,j,k`
`if (i==0.or.j==0.or.k==0) then`
 `correctNeighLabel=0`
`else`
 `correctNeighLabel=A(i,j,k)`
`endif`
`end function correctNeighLabel`
I'm being told correctNeighLabel has not had it's type declared. Any idea why @VladimirF?

Comment: @Pureferret: Because you didn't declare it's type in the function definition.

Comment: Silly me I just c/p what @VladimirF wrote. It now works! Great success :)

Answer (score 4):

It is not obligatory that Fortran accesses arrays starting from one.  Any starting value is allowed.   If it more convenient to you to have a zero indexed array, declare the array as:

```
real, dimension (0:N-1, 0:M-1) :: array
```

Or

```
real, dimension (0:N, 0:M) :: array
```

and have the 0 indices be extra to catch special cases.

This might be another solution to your problem, since zero index values would be legal.

Comment: Certainly true. It would be better choice in many situations.

Answer (score 3):

Another possible way to approach this, is to create an extended cluster label array (with index bounds starting at 0), which is equal to the cluster label array with a layer of zeroes tacked on the outside. You can then let your loop run safely over all values of jj, kk, and ll. It depends on the size of the array if this is a feasible solution.

```
integer :: extended_cluster_label(0:size(cluster_label,1),   &
                                  0:size(cluster_label,2),   &
                                  0:size(cluster_label,3)    &
                                 )

extended_cluster_label(0,:,:) = 0
extended_cluster_label(:,0,:) = 0
extended_cluster_label(:,:,0) = 0

extended_cluster_label(1:, 1:, 1:) = cluster_label
```